# WixUIExtension.dll could not load from the network path while creating MSI package using WIX

Tags: c#-4.0, wix, windows-installer

I am using WIX (Windows Installer XML 3.7) to create an MSI package.

This is in my `*.WIXPROJ` file

```
<ItemGroup>
    <WixExtension Include="WixUIExtension">
        <HintPath>$(WixToolPath)WixUIExtension.dll</HintPath>
        <Name>WixUIExtension</Name>
    </WixExtension>
</ItemGroup>
```

Also,

```
<PropertyGroup>  
    <ApplicationPath>\\BuildFolder</ApplicationPath>
    <WixToolPath>$(ApplicationPath)\BuildMSI\wix37-binaries\</WixToolPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

When creating MSI file from network path following error is occurred.

> The extension '\BuildFolder\wix37-binaries\WixUIExtension.dll' could not be loaded because of the following reason: Could not load file or assembly 'file://\BuildFolder\wix37-binaries\WixUIExtension.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

Please help me how to resolve this issue.

Regards,
Dileep

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<WixExtension Include="WixUIExtension">
  <HintPath>$(WixExtDir)\WixUIExtension.dll</HintPath>
  <Name>WixUIExtension</Name>
</WixExtension>
```